# Deleting Azure Container App takes long time and time out the pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-container-apps

I use Azure DevOps pipelines to create and destroy resources in Azure.

When destroying resources, I use `Remove-AzResourceGroup` and it works fine.

The issue is that I have multiple Container App Environments, and when deleting those, it takes at least 20-25 minutes, 3x of those will take more than an hour leading to a long-running pipeline and in most cases time-out, so I need to re-run the pipeline 2-3 time until the deletation is done. Even though I have set the job `timeoutInMinutes` to `0` which means theoretically infinite but still times out after when it reaches approx 60 min.

Is there a way to fire the delete process and forget without waiting?

Or an alternative/creative solution so I can overcome the long waiting running job.

Comment: This seems to be something for https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideas in @Daniel Mann answer are good, but I have meanwhile found a better solution for fire and forget. The part about trying to run the pipeline via the rest API call part from the other answer can be combined with my answer here as well. This will help to delete dependency resources that can not be deleted until other resources it depends on are deleted

I did use the following to delete multiple resources from a loop which will lead to waiting for a response of True or False which can take time for some resources and timeout the pipeline.

```
Remove-AzResourceGroup -Name "rg-name" -Force
```

Now let's put this in a `Start-Job` in the pipeline,

```
$name = 'rg-name'
$sb = [scriptblock]::Create("Remove-AzResourceGroup -Name '$name' -Force")
Start-Job -ScriptBlock $sb
```

The nice thing here, it will initiate a removal process but does not need to wait. Of course, when the agent is done, the job will be disposed of, but the removal process is already initiated. This way I have solved the issue of waiting time.

I put the code snippet in a loop of the resources I want to delete.

Snapshot from azdo

Before the change, it took more than 60 min for 3 attempts

[image]

After the new way, it took around 7 minutes

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hosted agents have a maximum runtime of 60 minutes. You can use a self-hosted agent which doesn't have this limitation.

Another alternative, and this is slightly hacky, would be to delete one item per pipeline run, then check if there are more to be deleted, and if so, use the REST APIs to re-trigger the pipeline. So if you have 5 items that need to be run, it would automatically run the pipeline 5 times.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer, Self-hosting is sadly not possible at this stage. There are good ideas in the answer, thump up. Btw I was also considering trying Azure rest API resource deletion, do you have any experience with it?

Comment: Meanwhile, I have made a breakthrough with a simpler solution.